# error: request for member is of non-class type string & char

Tags: c++, string, linked-list

this is my Node Structure;

```cpp
class Node
{
public:
    string data;
    Node *next;
    Node *child;
};
Node *
createList(string *arr, int n)
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            tmp = head = new Node();
        }
        else
        {
            tmp->next = new Node();
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }

        tmp->data = arr[i];
        tmp->next = tmp->child = NULL;
    }
    return head;
}
```

This is the problem where I get.

```cpp
    filesystem::path cwd = filesystem::current_path();
    int file_count;
    vector files = filesInDir(cwd, file_count);

    string file_names[file_count];
    string file_extensions[file_count];
    string file_sizes[file_count];

    for (int i = 0; i < file_count; ++i)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < file_count; ++i)
        {
            file_names.push_back(files[i + 0 * file_count]);
            file_extensions.push_back(files[i + 1 * file_count]);
            file_sizes.push_back(files[i + 2 * file_count]);
        }
    }

    Node *head1 = createList(file_names, file_count);
    Node *head2 = createList(file_extensions, file_count);
    Node *head3 = createList(file_sizes, file_count);
```

```
main.cpp:54:24: error: request for member 'push_back' in 'file_names', which is of non-class type 'std::string [file_count]' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> [file_count]'}
   54 |             file_names.push_back(files[i + 0 * file_count]);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~
```

I'm trying to read all files in the current directory, and save them into like `vector((file_name_1, file_extension_1, file_size_1), ......)`(All of them in the string format). I need to use multi linked list to store them, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: C arrays do not have methods.

Comment: What is a multi-linked list or rather how you want to use it in this case?

Comment: @Quimby "*What is a multi-linked list*" - the OP is referring to a multi-dimensional linked list, aka a tree, where a given node has both sibling nodes and child nodes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau OKay, thanks for the explanation, never heard that term used for a tree.

Answer (score 0):

`push_back()` is a method of standard C++ containers, like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  But you are trying to call it on C-style variable-length arrays instead, which do not have methods (and BTW, they are [NOT part of standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097)).

Since you are already using `std::vector` anyway for the return value of `filesInDir()`, simply use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `std::string[]` for your variable-length arrays, eg:

```
vector<string> file_names;
file_names.reserve(file_count);

// populate file_names as needed ...

Node *head1 = createList(file_names.data(), file_names.size());
...
```

Do the same with the `file_extensions` and `file_sizes` arrays, too.

---

Also, since you are using the standard library anyway (for `std::string`, `std::vector`, and `std::filesystem`), consider using [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (double-linked) or [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) (single-linked) for the linked lists, instead of using a manual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with;

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < file_count; ++i)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < file_count; ++i)
        {
            file_names[i] = (files[i + 0 * file_count]);
            file_extensions[i] = (files[i + 1 * file_count]);
            file_sizes[i] = (files[i + 2 * file_count]);
        }
    }
```

but this time I needed to add tail pointer to node structure, I'm trying to solve that

```cpp
class Node
{
public:
    string data;
    Node *next;
    Node *child;
};

Node *
createList(string *arr, int n)
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            tmp = head = new Node();
        }
        else
        {
            tmp->next = new Node();
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }

        tmp->data = arr[i];
        tmp->next = tmp->child = NULL;
    }
    return head;
}
```